# Using database migrations in a pkg binary

Tags: node.js, database-migration, knex.js

I have a nodejs app that I use PKG to create linux binary for new releases. I want to add knex db migration feature to it but when I run my binary, I get the following error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app/migrations'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/app/migrations'
}
```

My binary resides in `/app` and my guess is that it's looking for an actual folder there (which doesn't exist because I expect it to be a part of the binary).

For your information, using knex migrations makes me add a configuration file named `knexfile.js` and a folder named `migrations` to my project home directory.
I added the `scripts` line to the pkg section of my `package.json` but the problem persists:

```
"pkg": {
  "scripts": ["migrations/**/*", "knexfile.js"],
  "assets": "dist/**/*"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this same problem but I'm using db-migrate.  Keep in mind, in the packaged executable, pkg uses the base folder /snapshot so in your node file, you'll want to set your cwd to /snapshot/(project home directory).   Their documentation talks more about it.  Also, pkg.assets configuration array does not seem to actually do anything.  Use path.join(__dirname, "migrations") in your node file to import the migrations folder into your executable